# How to specify a pair of elements with a particular property as underscript?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have $n$ pairs $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$, how do I specify for instance all the pairs where $y$ value is zero succinctly?
I'm using it for the underscript of a sum to subset it.

Comment: Have you considered [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) instead?

Comment: That isn't $n$ sets of pairs; that's _one_ set of $n$ pairs. $\qquad$

Comment: something like $\sum_{y_k = 0} x_k$? it is sloppy, but most would understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define an indexing set and iterate over that instead. Let:
$$
A = \{k \in \{1, \ldots, n\} \mid y_k = 0\}
$$
Then we want:
$$
\sum_{k \in A} f(x_k, y_k)
$$